# loop immutablejs Map object inside react render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, redux, immutable.js

Basically i am using react redux and immutablejs. i am wrapping `fromJS` from immutable in my reducer which looks like this

```
const initialState = fromJS({
   data1: {},
});

export default function dataReducer(state = initialState, action){
   switch(action.type){
      case 'ONE':
      return state.setIn(['data1'], action.data1);
   }
}
```

In my `jsx` if i print `this.props.data1` i am able to print all values

```
render(){
    return(
        <div>
           {this.props.data1}
        </div>
    )
}
```

If i print `this.props.data1` i am getting `Map` object

[image]

Basically how do i loop this data using `.map`? since the data is in `Map` object

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the property of `data1` prop you need to back this props to js! 
you can do it by using `toJS()` function. for more info use this [link](https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js#converts-back-to-raw-javascript-objects).